# how to find the storage device (CPU or GPU) of data?

Tags: python, numpy, gpu

I wrote a function calculated on GPU, then I got some data and transformed them into python numpy.ndarray form. Is there a method that I can check the storage device (CPU or GPU) of the data?

I used minpy supporting GPU parallelization to get an array with the type of array.ndArray that should be saved on GPU memory, then I used function of asnumpy to convert it into numpy array form. Now I would like to know if there is a way I can find where the transformed numpy array data is.

Comment: This is a strange question because CPU and GPU are processor units (PU), not storage devices (SD). Can you give a bit of context, perhaps some code for a minimal, reproducible example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @PauloScardine perhaps they mean video memory on the GPU?

Comment: Maybe check the datatype : `arr.dtype`, where `arr` is the data.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Do you think he wants to know if some Python object is stored in the motherboard's RAM memory or in the video board dedicated RAM memory? It is a long shot, the OP really should update the question with a pinch of context. Perhaps the most important question is: why is the OP concerned about this?

Comment: @PauloScardine I was trying to be charitable in my interpretation. OP did indeed update, and now I think that may actually be what they are intending. It still isn't particularly clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. In your case I think it's stored on the host (cpu). Newer versions of Cuda (https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/) would transparently shuffle the memory from the gpu to the cpu or vice versa depending on if you are accessing the memory from the cpu or gpu. Older versions would probably give you an access violation if you access memory stored on the gpu from the cpu. My guess is that as you have successfully converted the data to an numpy array,  it is now stored on the host (cpu). Checking the raw pointer could work IF the memory was allocated with Cuda. In this case `cudaPointerGetAttributes` could give you this information.

If you can access it from python/numpy it is certainly stored on the host (cpu).